# Create a TCP half open connection with bash command

Tags: linux, networking, bash, tcp

Is there a way to (easily) create a TCP half-open connection using a bash command with common Linux tooling?

I want to monitor availability of a remote server using such mechanism. I know it is also used for such monitoring in TCP load balancer.

The TCP messages I would to see is `SYN->SYN-ACK<-RST`. Final `RST` ensures the TCP socket is not hurting the server by keeping half-open sockets alive.

Comment: Bash itself doesn't contain any networking code, so your question boils down to, "are there any command-line tools I can call from bash to create a half-open TCP connection". Also note that there's no way to bring up a TCP connection only halfway. To have a half-open connection, you bring the connection up all the way and then half-close it.

Comment: Indeed I agree there is nothing inside batch about networking but it is the way I would like to call a networking tool to half create a TCP session. I would like to avoid creating the TCP session to minimize the impact of the operation for the remote side (`SYN`+`SYN-ACK` only if I have understood correctly the notion of half-open)

Comment: I'm not sure a half-open connection impacts the server side less, since it means the server has to maintain the state of the never-going-to-happen connection until it times out. This is how [SYN flood DDoS attacks](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/syn-flood-ddos-attack/) work. One half-open connection isn't a big deal, but IMO it'd be polite to at least send an RST to cancel it.

Comment: You might be able to use hping3 to do what you're looking for.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I clarified my question to add the `RST` at the end since the purpose is monitoring not flooding the remote server, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nping` tool included in `nmap` can be used for such use case. It sends a SYN, wait SYN-ACK then sends RST. It needs an access to raw socket which is only accessible with `CAP_NET_RAW` capability. Usually only root user has such capability.

```
$ sudo nping --tcp 1.1.1.1  -p 443 -c 1
```

The TCP dump validating only the 3 TCP packets are present.

```
$ sudo ngrep -eqxtd en0 '.' 'host 1.1.1.1'
interface: en0 (192.168.2.0/255.255.255.0)
filter: ( host 1.1.1.1 ) and ((ip || ip6) || (vlan && (ip || ip6)))
match: .

T 2020/10/02 10:27:06.261689 192.168.2.26:34769 -> 1.1.1.1:443 [S] #1

T 2020/10/02 10:27:06.269662 1.1.1.1:443 -> 192.168.2.26:34769 [AS] #2
  00 00                                                 ..              

T 2020/10/02 10:27:06.269739 192.168.2.26:34769 -> 1.1.1.1:443 [R] #3
```